# Issue when trying to add user validation

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

Trying to add validation to user input.

So the code is:

```
print ('Does this service require an SFP Module? (y/n): ')
while True:
    sfpreq = input()
    if sfpreq != 'y' or 'n':
        print("You must enter either y or n")
        continue
    else:
        break
```

So even when the user enters 'n' it returns the "print("You must enter either y or n")" and continues the loop.

I have tried setting the variabl manually to and also tried another convention I found on realpython and also removed the if statement from the while loop:

```
sfpreq = "n"
if sfpreq != 'y' or sfpreq != 'n':
   print("You must enter either y or n")
else:
   print("Test")
```

Again it just returns:

```
admin@MacBook-Pro Learning Folder % python3 test22.py
You must enter either y or n
```

Am I just missing something very fundamental here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem with the logic

```py
sfpreq = "n"
if sfpreq != 'y' or sfpreq != 'n':
   print("You must enter either y or n")
else:
   print("Test")
```

Here, when you enter the `if` loop,
`sfpreq != 'y'` is validated as `True` and  `sfpreq != 'n'` is validated as  `False`. 
Now `True` `OR` `False` statement in boolean algebra equates to `True`.
So, the `if` loop gets executed  and `You must enter either y or n` is printed.
See, more about boolean algebra [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/computer_logical_organization/boolean_algebra.htm)

## A better solution

```py
sfpreq = "n"
if sfpreq not in {"y","n"}:
   print("You must enter either y or n")
else:
   print("Test")
```

So, here we are checking if `y` or `n` is not there in the set `{"y","n"}`. As in this case, `sfpreq` is there in that set so,the `else` statement gets executed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, that makes a lot more sense.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow.  If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers